# Probability of learners chosen at random

Tags: probability

There are $14$ boys and $15$ girls in the class. What is the probability that a specific group of $3$ boys and $2$ girls is chosen, if the learners are chosen at random?

I know the answer is $\frac{28}{87}$.

My issue is with how to get there.

I understand the equation will be $\frac{14}{29} * \frac{13}{28} * \frac{12}{27} * \frac{15}{26} * \frac{14}{25}$

But that answer gives me $\frac{14}{435}$

What am i doing wrong, please help?

Comment: What is the size of the group that is chosen?

Comment: Hint: In your attempt you have ignored that boys and girls can be chosen in any order. You took the order to be BBBGG but it could be GBGBB or many other combinations

Comment: Instance of [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution)

Answer (score 1):

Number of combinations to choose $3$ boys out of $14$ is $C_{3}^{14}=\frac{14!}{3!(14-3)!}$.

Combinations to choose $2$ girls out of $15$:  $C_{2}^{15}=\frac{15!}{2!(15-2)!}$.

Combinations to choose $5(=2+3)$ persons out of $29(=14+15)$: $C_{5}^{29}=\frac{29!}{5!(29-5)!}$.

As we expect each combination to be equally probable, then answer is quotient:
$$
\frac{C^{14}_3C^{15}_2}{C^{29}_5}=\frac{28}{87}
$$ 
where $C^{14}_3C^{15}_2$ is total number of combinations to choose $3$ boys out of $14$ and $2$ girls out of $15$.